# Zabbix Server with Multiple NIC (one on different VLAN) - Monitor a host from both NIC?

Tags: networking, monitoring, zabbix

Basically we have many of servers configured for internal use only. I want to ensure the internal services are preserved as internal by checking a host using the local subnet (allowed - this checks if services are up and working), and that the internal services are indeed internal (make sure the services are "down" when checking from different subnet (vlan))

Is there an easy way to do this in Zabbix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with 1.8, you can create two hosts (one per interface) and monitor services on these.

for zabbix 2.0, support of multiple interfaces for hosts will be available, so then you could configure that using a single host. you would probably have two separate templates (one providing a check that service runs, another - that it's not running), then assign the items from those templates to the interfaces.
one issue with that approach might be requirement for the keys to be unique per host, so you might have to trick zabbix a bit by adding port to one of the items or similar